# Python Fabric: Sending a SIGINT (CTRL+C)

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I had two queries here.

Ive written a script in python which tails live logs on a remote server.

1. How do i have **"control+c"** on my keyboard end the live tail remotely?
2. How do i send **"control+c"** using fabric to the remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric may be a little too high level for what you're trying to do.  You may want to try using the underlying library that fabric is using: [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/).